# How to edit snapshot dependencies

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, maven-3, snapshot

I am very new to the industry, so apologies in advance for the very likely stupidity of the question.
In the team, we work with Intellij IDEA 13 as IDE, and use Maven 3 for our projects. We provide a few online services and portals, and I'm just starting to work on one: the project has several dependencies that are shared by other older projects, some are JAR archives, some are WARs...

To my questions re: how to edit those dependencies locally (e.g. editing a resources.properties was the case I had in mind) my tutor suggested turning the dependencies into snapshots and work with those.
What I managed to do was create a copy of the appropriate folders in my local repository and change wherever the version of the dependency was in the name or in the files, then modify my pom.xml files.

Now, this works perfectly if I open the JAR/WAR and edit some file, but I'd like to be able to do it from my IDE, also cause not being able to suggests I'm probably doing this in a wrong way. Do I need to somehow unpack the dependency to be able to do so? Is my entire approach wrong?

P.S.: I would ask someone in my office, but oddly enough none of those who could help are at work today anymore!

Comment: Seems to me like you need to be snuggling up with a good book on Maven, because your whole question stems from not understanding what Maven is for and how you apply it. The advice you were given sounds to me like you should have changed some dependency versions in poms to -SNAPSHOT versions to be using the latest in-development versions of those dependencies, but that is also very largely a guess, having no access to your environment to see what the real truth is.

Comment: As much as that is definitely true, it's not too feasible right now, as I've been "thrown" into Spring and Maven and more, and am trying to avoid having to read too many books after work, cause time is a limited resource hehe.
The advice was aimed at me being able to modify the dependencies, more than having the latest versions (which, I believe, are the version I do currently have).
But as you point out I still have many gaps in my Maven "knowledge" so I can't be entirely sure myself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If none of your colleagues was able to help you, I am afraid there might be something else hidden.

However, let's try it!

I am guessing, here, that your `resources.properties` is a part of his own project. Project handled by Maven and expressed as a dependency in one of your main project.

I am also guessing that your main projects are WARs (Webapps mostly, services, portals) and the JARs are libraries, configurations, etc...)

Therefore, I am guessing that your webapps are referencing some libraries as Maven dependencies, to a specific version.

That said, IntelliJ (and other IDE) can easily handle modification of either JARs and WARs related to each other via Maven as long as the visioning is meaningful.

---

Note: Having `-SNAPSHOT` at the end of the version number tell to Maven NOT to cache the package. On the opposite, a definitive version number is considered as `released` and is only fetched from the cache. This is important because with a `SNAPSHOT`, you can publish an illimited number of time and it is guaranteed to have the latest version.

Note: Doing `mvn clean install` publish a package into your local Maven repository (generally located in *~/.m2*) and is only available to you.

---

The general good practice is to have, in all the development branches of your DVCS, all your owned, often modified projects (Don't be too greedy, it depend on the situation) as SNAPSHOT. And during a release (Maven has a specific plugin for that) change all the versions to a final one, attributed in this precise moment (You never know if you will need a minimal version or a major).
Your code, then, has always the SNAPSHOT number of your expected next release.

Finally, I think that in your case, if you choose to change the `pom.xml` of one of your **library** for a SNAPSHOT, you should change the `pom.xml` of the root **project** to correspond.

If this dependency version is the same, then, you can add your library as a `module` within IntelliJ and the IDE will do the math to figure that the Maven dep and the Java module are the same entity.

I don't even know if that's help you (I'm not even sure if it's clear), but I hope it will make you ask more questions about what you need. Your co-workers will probably be able to help you more.

Comment: It's not that they weren't able to help: no developer in my team is here this afternoon, so I currently don't really have anyone to ask to.
I mostly figure out part of what you just explained and if I don't misread it I think part of it is what I actually did. What I don't seem to be able to figure out is modifying files (like the aforementioned resources.properties I'm trying to modify from a library) but adding the library as a module sounds like something that could address my issues.
I will try to investigate during the weekend and find some good and synthetic book on Maven like suggested!

Comment: So it turns out this was more or less it, the bit I was missing was that they thought I would be able to checkout the project from SVN, but I didn't in fact have access to that specific project.
After that was done, I just needed to add it as module and then use that local snapshot version as dependency.
Thanks for the answer!